# How to connect to USB device from iOS with Xcode or swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to connect USB camera to iOS in Xcode using Swift or Objective C.

I saw online to try and use IOKit.framework, but I believe it's for MAC, which I'm not using. dos NSSstring converters but I'm unsure that will work either. I'm trying to do it through iOS.

I also have a WIFI adapter that will connect to my NIKON DSLR and shoot photos to a PC over wifi but not sure how to get the iOS device to connect and download these images.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are already apps that do this though? There is an app on the app store called QDSLR that will transfer photos from NIKON which has a connect to PC mode, and then sends an image instantly to the IOS device app. Im just trying to replicate this function in a similar way to use with my own app.

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like this isn't possible, at least for what you want.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502)

> Communicating with an external accessory requires you to work closely
>   with the accessory manufacturer to understand the services provided by
>   that accessory. ***Manufacturers must build explicit support into their
>   accessory hardware for communicating with iOS.*** As part of this
>   support, an accessory must support at least one command protocol

These USB devices obviously have not been designed with iOS in mind, so there is a very small chance you can get it to work the apple way.

Alternatively, you can look into jailbreaking and that sorta deal with the cameraconnectionkit library. This is way out of my scope though, so good luck!